# How to plot file.mat or file.csv using python with plotly?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

df=pd.read_csv('samples.csv', sep=',',header=None)
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at trying to make a plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to Plotly docs from [this link](https://plot.ly/python/plot-data-from-csv/). It has an easy and simple to follow docs.
In a nutshell, you can create a table from data in your file and then call `py.iplot` with its parameters as stated in below code

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample-data.csv')
sample_data_table = FF.create_table(df.head())
py.iplot(sample_data_table, filename='sample-data-table')
```